# Angular 2/4 how to POST JSON data made by Form

Tags: forms, angular-cli, angular2-forms, angular5

I'm using FormBuilder for make JSON data,
I have made this form using FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl

this is my forms code

```
<form [formGroup]="SearchForm" (ngSubmit)="search(SearchForm.value)" name="SearchForms">
    <input type="text" formControlName="checkin" value="12:00" placeholder="12:00" readonly> In 
    <input type="text" formControlName="checkout" value="10:00" placeholder="10:00" readonly> Out
    <input type="text" formControlName="guest"> Guest 
    <input type="text" formControlName="room"> Room
    <select formControlName="position">
        <option value="sky">sky</option>
        <option value="earth">Earth</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" formControlName="date" name="date" value="{{selected_date}}">
    <input type="hidden" formControlName="location"  name="location" value="{{location}}">
    <button class="btn shadow" type="submit"> Search </button>
</form>
```

and this my component.ts file

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
http: any;

  SearchForm : FormGroup;
  post:any;

  location: string ='';
  date:string = '';
  checkin:string='';
  checkout:string='';
  guest:number;
  room:number;
  position:string='';

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) 
  { 
    this.SearchForm = fb.group({
      'location' : [null],
      'date' : [null],
      'checkin' : [null],
      'checkout' : [null],
      'guest' : [null],
      'room' : [null],
      'position' : [null],      
    });
  }

  search(post) 
  {
    this.location = post.location;
    this.date     = post.date;
    this.checkin  = post.checkin;
    this.checkout = post.checkout;
    this.guest    = post.guest;
    this.room     = post.room;
    this.position = post.position;  

     this.http.post('http://localhost:4200/searchrequest',JSON.stringify(this.SearchForm))
  }
  ngOnInit() 
  {

    this.SearchForm = new FormGroup(
      {
        location: new FormControl(),
        date: new FormControl(),
        checkin: new FormControl(),
        checkout: new FormControl(),
        guest: new FormControl(),
        room: new FormControl(),
        position:new FormControl()
      });}
```

I have no idea what I should fo next for post data from `SearchForm` I have made.

Any help form my project? if someone has a link for example you can share it here.

Thanks before

Comment: In above code snippet there is no need to declare post:any; You can follow corrected code given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48366307/4420586 thread

Answer (score 2):

```
  search(post) 
  {
    this.location = post.location;
    this.date     = post.date;
    this.checkin  = post.checkin;
    this.checkout = post.checkout;
    this.guest    = post.guest;
    this.room     = post.room;
    this.position = post.position;  

     this.http.post('http://localhost:4200/searchrequest',JSON.stringify(this.SearchForm))
  }
```

should be

```
  search(post) 
  {
     this.http.post('http://localhost:4200/searchrequest',JSON.stringify(post))
  }
```

you are currently assigning all the form values to the component Instance members when you can just as easily send the entire form value.

and you also initialize the searchForm twice, once with the FormBuilder service and the other time with a new FormGroup instance, which are doing exactly the same thing. you can remove the entire ngOnInit() function since you do it already in the constructor.

angular 5 FormBuilder doc's: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder

adding @marcidius comment as its a valuable part of the solution.

> To fix that error you need to add a private http member to your
>   constructor: constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: Http)
>   Also, in your example you don't even need to be passing the SearchForm
>   to that function since it is a class member already. Reactive Forms`
>   values are updated via their bindings so any update to the form
>   elements updates the model automatically. Just call this.searchForm in
>   the JSON.stringify(...) but don't worry about passing it into the
>   function.

Comment: i got error like this `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined`

Comment: on the stringify function?

Comment: To fix that error you need to add a private http member to your constructor:

`constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: Http)`

Also, in your example you don't even need to be passing the SearchForm to that function since it is a class member already.  Reactive Forms` values are updated via their bindings so any update to the form elements updates the model automatically.  Just call `this.searchForm` in the JSON.stringify(...) but don't worry about passing it into the function.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to get my this.contactForm.value in order to get the object of values . Than i did the stringify